# Programatically select the largest image from an array of image URLS in PHP?

Tags: php, image

I've got an array with 4-5 local image urls in it.

I want to programatically return the URL of the largest image by image dimension in the array.  How do I do that?

Comment: Largest in what way?  Dimensions or file size?  If the former, you'll need to download them all and test them if they're not marked.

Comment: They're all downloaded.  These are local files.  Also, I just edited my question to specify largest by image dimension. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

A very simplistic approach would be:

```
$files = array_combine($filenames,
  array_map("array_sum", array_map("getimagesize", $filenames))
);
arsort($files);

print key($files);    # largest image
```

This just adds $width+$height and checks for which file this adds up to the largest amount. Similar results to multiplying the two values. But in practice you might want to manually search for the `max()` value of width and height, if a 15x1000 should be treated as larger than 550x550.

Comment: Very nice lean function, array_map is so useful! Aside, I have not seen `print` used in quite some time.

Answer (score 4):

[getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) is what you want here.  I've coded this in a very learn-friendly way.  There are more advanced ways to do this, but they sometimes get obtuse.

```
$largest = -1;
$largest_image = null;

foreach ($images as $image)
{
    $size = getimagesize($image);
    $val = $size[0] * $size[1];
    if ($val > $largest)
    {
        $largest_image = $image;
        $largest = $val;
    }
}
if ($largest_image != null) 
{
   // do magic
}
```